# ¿Como buscar si un elemento existe dentro de un array de texto en C#?

Tags: c#, array

Buenas ando aprendiendo C# y me encuentro con un quebradero de cabeza del que no logro salir.

Estoy intentando crear una función la cual contiene un array de tipo string, la idea es que la funcion recibe un parametro y debe buscar si ese mismo parametro existe dentro del array, despues en funcion de si existe o no ejecutara una orden o otra.

El codigo por ahora es tal que asi:

```
public static void comprobador(string comando)
{
string[] ciudad = { "Madrid", "Barcelona" };
bool existe;

if (existe == true)
{
console.writeline("Existe");
}
else
{
console.writeline("no existe");
}

}
```

creo que mi problema radica en que no se exactamente como buscar dentro del array, ni como saber si existe algo en el array, he visto temas sobre listas, foreach, etc

Me estoy liando un poco porque toda la informacion que encuentro sobre el uso de arrays con texto me resulta un poco contradictoria o muy compleja para algo tan relativamente simple. Dado que vengo de otros lenguajes como python donde no habia una distincion tan clara entre tipos de variables me resulta todo muy confuso. ¿Alguien me pude ayudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `Contains` de *Linq*.

```
bool existe = ciudad.Contains(comando);
```

Donde `comando` es el objeto que quieres buscar.
Te dejo [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1) la documentación del método.

Para poder usarlo, deberás poner el `using System.Linq;`.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar hacerlo con un ciclo `FOR`:

```
Boolean existeEnArray = false;
for(int i = 0; i < tuArray.Length; i++){
   if(tuArray[i] == tuCadena){
       exiteEnArray = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tambien lo he probado y funciona